# Compare and see changes with paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning

We know paper_trail has the power to undo changes. But is there a way to see what the changes are so that we know which version to undo to? Better still, we can compare the changes side-by-side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there's no in-built way to see what changed between one version and the next, though I'm considering changing that.  However you have a few options: see the README section Diffing Versions.

Comment: That should be where I would begin. Thanks. I think it will be wonderful if you could include comparing changes, thus making paper_trail an out-of-the-box solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @Andy Stewart what about his issue https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/60 ? looks like it does what is asked in this question, I see it was merged to v 2.2.7 and I have 2.7.2, does it mean that feature to show what was changed is enabled?

Comment: @magnum2002 Yes, that's right.  You may need to run a migration to start storing the object changes - see the README for details.